# Rails Obtener un valor desde una llamada utilizando AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails, controller

Estoy tratando de asignar a una variable de ruby el valor de una variable el cual obtengo con JS, se que lo tengo que hacer con AJAX y me gustaría lograrlo sin usar ninguna gema, logro enviar desde mi vista al servidor que este procese el valor y lo envíe de vuelta, pero no puedo asignarlo al valor de mi variable en la vista. cuando quiero imprimir el valor no me arroja nada.

controlador funcion.

```
def check_validity
 @value = params[:coupon]
 return (@value)
end
```

vista llamada.

```
$('.btn-floating.btn-sm.btn-outline-danger.shadow-sm').click(function() {

 var d = $(this).data('datac');      
 //alert(d); 
 console.log('d: '+d);
 $id = parseInt(d.split(",")[0]);
 //$div = '';

 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "check_validity",
     data: {coupon: $id},
     success: function(data) {
        console.log('DATA VALUE <%= @value %>')
     },
     error: function(exception){
        console.log("Error! : "+exception);
     }
 });

});
```

Gracias y espero su ayuda.

Comment: Por lo pronto, veo un par de problemas menores, pero antes de eso quisiera aclarar. O sea te está cargando todo el código de la vista en el browser, pero `@value` no asigna ningún valor, ¿a eso te refieres? y lo que te retorna desde el servidor, ¿está siendo evaluado a nivel de js? ¿desde dónde llamas a `check_validity`, desde ese mismo código de vista que muestras o desde otra parte? ¿supuestamente al llamar a `check_validity` debería refrescar ese mismo código que ya tienes cargado en la vista?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo veo veo es tema de cómo estas accediendo al método, de hecho no necesita el `return(@value)`.

El cómo lo estas pasando está bien ejemplo:

```
var myLatLng = {lat: <%= @user.latitude %>, lng: <%= @user.longitude %>};
```

Esto es en el caso de pasarle valores a un mapa.

Pero en tu caso podrías validar antes lo que estas pasando por parámetro a `@value = params[:coupon]`

Rails ya cuenta con este método que te puede ayudar `rails console`

```
# rails console
> ''.present?
=> false
> ''.presence
=> nil
> 'default'.present?
=> true
> 'default'.presence
=> "default"
```

Sería algo así:

```
if params[:coupon].present?
 @value = params[:coupon]
else
  'do something'
end
```